# How can I use instanceof Keyword Java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, integer, instanceof

Is this the right way of validating using the instanceof keyword in java? Can I not use the || operator with this keyword? I am seeing errors in the line where I am writing the if condition to check if FieldName < = 0 and also when I am checking if it is equal to null or empty. Can anyone help me with the right way of writing the following piece of code. Thank you.

```
public static boolean validation(Object FieldName, String Name) {
       if(FieldName instanceof Integer) {
         if ((int) FieldName < = 0) {

         errorCode = "EXCEPTION";
         errorMsg = "Required field " + Name + " was not provided";
         logger.debug(Name+ " is null ");
           return true;
 }
   else {
} 
}
   else if (FieldName instanceof String) {
      if(FieldName == null || FieldName.equals("")) {
        errorCode = "EXCEPTION";
        errorMsg = "Required field " +Name+" was not provided";
        logger.debug(Name+" is null ");
          return true;

 }
  //Here I check the fields for null or empty 
}
```

Comment: the problem is probably a syntax error, it should be not be `< =` but `<=`

Answer (score 0):

Why not have two methods, one which takes an Integer and validates that, and one that validates Strings? Would that be simpler?

Comment: Why is your answer a question? :)

Comment: I would like it more simpler by having one single method for validation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh.  The one method that does all.  That's just not how OO was intended.

Comment: My answer was a question, but I think @zebango45 get's the point, as emphasized by Erwin's comment. If you can design your solution so each method does one thing and one thing only, the solution is a lot simpler than 'one method that does all' - that's never a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

The line needs to be changed to

```
if (((int) FieldName) <= 0) {
```

when you don't put the parentheses around the cast completely the compiler will still believe it is an object and not an integer.

Comment: It still gives me an error stating "cannot cast from an object to an int"

Answer (score 0):

Try this. change the if and else body according to you

```
public static boolean validation(Object FieldName, String Name) {
  if (FieldName instanceof Integer) {
    if (((Integer)FieldName) <= 0) {

    //an integer <= 0

      return true;
   } else {
    // an integer >= 0
      return true;
  }
 } else if (FieldName instanceof String) {
   if (FieldName == null || FieldName.equals("")) {

   // a String empty or null

     return true;

   }
  else {
     // a String non empty
     return true;
   }

 }
 return false;
}
```